# How to get the promise that failed in catch block using async/await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm converting some code from `.then/.catch` to `async/await`. I need to access the original promise that fails in the catch block for logging purposes.

Orignal code:

```
  const myPromise = somePromise()

  myPromsise.then(() => {
    //...
  }).catch((error) => {
    errorLogger(error, myPromise) // The way we log things requires the original promise to be passed to the error logger.
  }
```

With try catch

```
  try {
    const myPromise = await somePromise()
    //...
  } catch (error) {
    errorLogger(error, myPromise) // myPromise is not available in catch block due to scope.
  }
```

How can I access the promise in the catch block?

Comment: Have you tried to just define `const myPromise` outside the try clause and then set it inside try with `myPromise = await somePromise()`?

Comment: In the second variant, the `const myPromise` does not contain a promise, it contains the result value. It may all be just sample code, but still, the sample could be better.

Comment: Slightly unconventional but you could throw the promise with a custom exception which you can try to catch ?

Comment: @Geshode - you'd use `let` in that case

Comment: "*The way we log things requires the original promise to be passed to the error logger.*" - why? This doesn't make sense, there are many ways code can fail without a promise being available. Really all the information that the logger needs should be contained in the error object that is thrown as the exception. Fix your logging.

Comment: @Bergi because it's a not great codebase and that's the established pattern. Changing an established pattern like this requires an incredible amount of bureaucratic debate with multiple teams, especially since it's related to logging.In the meantime, I can make some changes, like not mixing async/await & promise chains, using Promise constructors unnecessarily, race conditions, etc.

Comment: @MatthewMoran But what does the logger even do with the promise? There's no information stored on it that it should be able to access. What happens when you pass nothing (or an empty object) instead of the promise?

Comment: @Bergi honestly I have no idea. I have not dug deep enough into our logging at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting `myPromise()` to the promise. By using `await` you're setting it to what the promise resolves to.

To get the promise itself, assign the function to a variable without using `await`. You can then use `await` separately to get the resolved value.

```
const myPromise = somePromise();
try {
    const myValue = await myPromise;
    //...
} catch (error) {
    errorLogger(error, myPromise);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good to remember that `await` is waiting on what the promise resolves to.

Answer (score 0):

> The way we log things requires the original promise to be passed to the error logger.

Why? This doesn't make sense, there are many ways code can fail without a promise being available. Really all the information that the logger needs should be contained in the error object that is thrown as the exception. Fix your logging.

But if you must, I would start with

```
try {
  const myPromise = somePromise();
  await myPromise.catch(err => { err.promise = myPromise; throw err; });
  …
} catch (error) {
  errorLogger(error, error.promise)
}
```